# Fast sound analysis in Processing (Minim library)

Tags: audio, analysis, processing, minim

I'm collecting data from audio files based on sound analysis averaged per seconds and I'm wondering if there's a way to speed it up, given that I don't have to listen to the audio while analyzing it.
But I don't know if the draw() loop specific of Processing could let me do that. Also, the Minim library seems only to process audio in real time so I'm asking if anybody knows different.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Ess library?   It looks like the AudioFile.read() method will let you retrieve all the samples at once.   Then you can process them in whatever size chunk you like.

Answer (score 0):

In the ForwardFFT sample that comes with Processing, `fft.forward()` is called once per frame, so there is nothing that stops you from calling the `fft.forward()` function multiple times in setup to get your data. Here's how what I'd add in `setup()` of the ForwardFFT sample to get the data:

```
void setup()
{
  size(512, 200);
  minim = new Minim(this);

  jingle = minim.loadFile("jingle.mp3", 2048);
  jingle.loop();
  // create an FFT object that has a time-domain buffer the same size as jingle's sample buffer
  // note that this needs to be a power of two and that it means the size of the spectrum
  // will be 512. see the online tutorial for more info.
  fft = new FFT(jingle.bufferSize(), jingle.sampleRate());

  println("fft analysis  start");
  int now = millis();

  int trackLength = jingle.length();//length in millis
  int trackSeconds= (int)trackLength/1000; //length in seconds
  int specSize    = fft.specSize();  //how many fft bands
  float[][] fftData = new float[trackSeconds][specSize];//store fft bands here, for each time step
  for(int t = 0 ; t < trackSeconds; t++){//time step in seconds
    fft.forward(jingle.mix);//analyse fft
    for(int b = 0; b < specSize; b++){//loop through bands
      fftData[t][b] = fft.getBand(b);//store each band
    }
  } 

  println("fft analysis end, took: " + (millis()-now) + " ms");

  textFont(createFont("SanSerif", 12));
  windowName = "None";
}
```

Not sure what you want to do with the data, but are you sure you sure that sampling FFT once per second will give you enough data ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ddf.minim.ugens.FilePlayer`, and use `patch()` to apply effects to it with other ugens. In your case, you might create a ugen that FFTs the input, and then another one that adds up all the inputs it receives over time and averages them when it's done. These must extend the class `ddf.minim.UGen`.